# Terminating process kills all results

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Using multiprocessing to evaluate some models.
Use a shared list to store the results.
Run the eval, add the results to the shared list.

If a eval process takes longer than x, then terminate the process.

So I run it, and the shared list 'results' has entries... unless a process is terminated, at which point it's empty.
**Why is the shared list 'results' empty when a process is terminated**, which should only affect inner_results.

I expect running 19 evaluations which work fine will result in 'results' having 19 entries.
BUT including the 20th which has errors results in no entries.
I'm still expecting 19 entries

```
multiprocessing_is_True = True
if multiprocessing_is_True:
    from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
    from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score

    # Create empty lists to store the results and names
    results = Manager().list()
    names = Manager().list()

    def evaluate_models(inner_models, inner_X_train, inner_Y_train, results, names):
        inner_results = []
        inner_names = []

        for name, model in inner_models:
            kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
            cv_results = cross_val_score(model, inner_X_train, inner_Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
            inner_results.append(cv_results)
            inner_names.append(name)
            print('%s: \t%f \t(%f)' % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))

        # Update the results and names in the shared lists
        results.extend(inner_results)
        names.extend(inner_names)


    # Create and start the process
    evaluation_process = Process(target=evaluate_models, args=(models, X_train, Y_train, results, names))
    evaluation_process.start()

    # Wait for the process to finish or timeout after 1 minute
    timeout = 60
    evaluation_process.join(timeout=timeout)


    # Check if the process is still alive
    if evaluation_process.is_alive():
        print(f"Model evaluation exceeded {timeout} seconds. Stopping evaluation of this model.")
        evaluation_process.terminate()


# Convert results to a regular list
results = list(results)
names = list(names)

# Find model with the highest accuracy
max_accuracy_mean = max(result.mean() for result in results)
```

Comment: If you terminate before process gets to `results.extend(inner_results)`, then no results.

Comment: do you mean no 'results' or no 'inner_results'?
I would expect that by terminating the process then no inner_results.
If it's 'results', then please explain this as this is where I am lost.